# What is the need of the statement of (num+mod)%mod?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

What is the need of the statement `ans = (ans + mod) % mod` in this program ?

Assume that `mod = 10^9+7`. This function is computing `a` to the power of `b` under mod operation in O(log(n)) complexity:

```
long long power(long long a, long long b)
{
    if (b == 0) 
        return 1ll;
    long long ans = power(a, b/2);
    ans = (ans * ans) % mod;
    ans = (ans + mod) % mod;
    if(b % 2 == 1)
        ans = (ans * a) % mod;
    ans = (ans + mod) % mod;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: **Reopen**: this is a sensible question, asked clearly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most common usage of such a construct is to make sure the result is non-negative. The standard `operator%` behaves differently for positive and negative arguments: for example, `4%3==1`, but `(-2)%3==-2`, while you might expect `(-2)%3==1` and `(-2)/3==-1`, which is mathematically more correct.

This behavior can often cause problems when modular arithmetic is used, and this trick of adding `mod` is often employed to obtain the mathematically more correct non-negative result. Instead of simply writing `a%b`, if `a` can be negative, one writes `(a%b+b)%b`.

However, its usage in the code in your question is strange. In that case, it is easier to assume that `a` is positive *before* calling the `power` function from the main code (for example, by making the main call like `power((a%mod+mod)%mod, b)`). Probably the author just wanted to get additional assurance of correctness, although it was not needed.

Comment: This statement power((a%mod+mod)%mod, b)) for function calling  is really good for avoiding to calculate it in each step of recursion. thanks..